# Can Azure Notification Hubs send a push notification in both SANDBOX and PRODUCTION in one request?

Tags: azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I'm using Azure Notification Hub as my service to send push notification to mobile devices.

I developed a simple node server to register and send push notification.

I have already done implementing push notification and mobile clients can now receive push from my server but specifically for SANDBOX and PRODUCTION.

Is there a way that my server can send push notification in both SANDBOX and PRODUCTION (together) in one request?

This is my code for sending push notification in SANDBOX/PRODUCTION

```
var payLoad = {
        aps: {
            alert: data
        }
    };
    azure.apns.send(tag, payLoad, function (err, reps){
        if(!err){
            cb({error: false});
        }else{
            cb({error: true, error_log: err});
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to do that. These are two intentionally separate and isolated environments.

Here's [an older blog post](https://peter78.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/apple-push-notification-service-deployment-tips/) that outlines basic facts about the two:

> General Rule of Thumbs:
>
> Keep in mind that the sandbox (development) environment is entirely
>   separate to the production environment. Let me repeat: Keep in mind
>   that the sandbox (development) environment is entirely separate to the
>   production environment. Mixing device tokens and certifications across
>   the environment will lead to a lot of nothing (that is, non
>   responses). Servers needs push certificates from the provisioning
>   portal. Clients register themselves with push services by
>   communicating with Apple servers. The two environments have items
>   needed specific to them. More specifically:
>
> Servers need a separate developer certificate and production
>   certificate. Client get a different device token when registering
>   themselves in development builds vs applications downloaded from the
>   App Store. Therefore, the following rules exist (unless you do some
>   hackery I’m not currently aware of):
>
> Development builds of your client (that is, any build put on your
>   device from the development environment including Ad Hoc) will get
>   development device tokens when registering with the APNS. Which means
>   you can’t test production server settings with at development build on
>   your client. Attempts to do so will lead to confusion and wasted time.
>   Production builds (that is, the app actually downloaded from the App
>   Store) will get production device tokens. These must be tested with
>   production APNS server settings.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I already assume that there is no way. but I appreciate your answer .. also providing a link is very helpful.